# How to find an application's entry point in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The question may apply to any programming language written in Visual Studio, but I am more concerned about C++.

Is there a way to easily determine the application entry point in Visual Studio?

For a relatively small application this could be easy, but for large ones, it will be pretty hard. In my particular case I know that the project which is set as startup is the one which has the entry point, but I was unable to find it, even though the application starts and runs well.

Comment: Isn't there a 'stop at entry point' option in the project's debug settings?

Comment: Hi @barakmanos I can not find it, can you be a little more specific about where this option is located?

Comment: Check [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx), which states that the functions `main`, `WinMain`, and `DllMain` are the three forms of the user-defined entry point.

Comment: Alternatively, just start your debugging process by hitting F10 or F11 rather than F5 (assuming default key bindings). It should step you into you entry point function and wait.

Comment: @WhozCraig make it an answer, please, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @meJustAndrew honestly I liked both of the answers already given, but its your question, so will do. It wasn't something I do to *find* entry points; its something I do to knowingly *start* at the main function (or whatever the config has been setup for using as the startup function).

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand, but your comment was a directly answer to my question, and it was the easiest thing to do, since one can have a hudge project, and searching for *main* will return a lot of results. And also to define a main you have to firstly know the type of main your application supports, to declare a simply main or WinMain or even DllMain, recompile the program (which may take a while) and then see where the errors are. This is why this is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find what C++ project is executable than search for `<ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>` in all your `*.vcxproj` files.

If you are looking for the entry point function inside this application, than search for `main`, `wmain` or `WinMain` functions.

Also entry point can be redefined with `/ENTRY` parameter, so you can check `Configuration Properties > Linker > Advanced > Entry Point` project parameter or search for `/ENTRY` in your `*.vcxproj`.

Comment: I just appreciate, some of the things here I already know, but what I am looking for is more like a simple way to do it, and WhozCraig in the comment posted it, but thank you very much!

Comment: @meJustAndrew Right, but in case when debug cannot be started you will be able to use the other approach.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, a fully compiled program can have only one defined `main` method. If there's more than one, the compiler will complain about "multiple definitions of main" or some other similarly worded message.

So, the simplest option is to do a search for the symbol `main` (or, if compiling as a Windows Subsystem program, `WinMain`) and figure out which ones correspond to the "startup" project. There shouldn't be that many, even in a relatively large solution.

Comment: I just appreciate, some of the things here I already know, but what I am looking for is more like a simple way to do it, and WhozCraig in the comment posted it, but thank you very much!

Comment: You may have quite a problem searching for a main function in a large project just based on the text. The expression "main" is quite a generic word appearing in comments and other... Offten I do things like searching for 'main(', but: 1) People sometimes make a space in front of the parenthesis 2) some people use macros to define main 3) In fact it is quite often to have multiple main functions but "#ifdef" them to build only in certain targets. This strategy is often used for tests... In this case you may need to go over hundreds of mains until you find the "real main".

Answer (score 1):

When desiring to *stop* execution at the top of the main/WinMain function while interactively debugging a process on Windows, I typically just use F10/F11 (assuming default C/C++ key bindings in the Visual Studio IDE) to instruct the debugger to single-step (which starts the process, then performs the step, then breaks).

Note this may not always do what you want. If you want to catch global initializations, object constructions, etc, these are already done before reaching `main` or `WinMain`. Those require additional debugging and setting breakpoints in CRT-source code for the *real* global startup code (which eventually calls your `main` or `WinMain`). But if you simply want to break-on-main-entry for a program built with debugging symbols, this is likely the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the little addition too!